# Can't use pyinstaller to convert my py file to exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have already installed pyinstaller
I am trying to use pyinstaller in cmd but I receive error:

command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=mc.ico mcservmng.py
```

error :

```
pyinstaller is not recognized as internal or external command
```

Comment: How did you install `pyinstaller`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your pyinstaller installation directory is non available through PATH.
See https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/installation.html

Or try to change directory to it before starting the pyinstaller:
like
C:\Python38\Scripts
or
cd /opt/pyinstaller
depending on your OS, Python version Directory to install chosen during the first install
and the try
pyinstaller --version
to check if it is available and runnable